# Will change name of an injected service change the behavior of transaction?

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 1.3.7, and I have two service, and I call a method of BService in AService as following:

```
BService {
  static boolean transactional = true

  public void bDoThings() {
    //doThings
    b.save()
  }
}

AService {

  static boolean transactional = true

  BService bProxy

  public void aDoThings() {
    //doSomethings
    bProxy.bDoThings()
    //doSomeOtherThings
    throw new RuntimeException()
  }
}
```

I think after throwing RuntimeException, aDoThings will be roll back, and b will not be saved. But only aDotThings is roll back, b is still persisted.

But when I change

```
BService bProxy
```

to

```
BService bService
```

or to

```
def bService
```

Everything works fine.So I wonder why this happens, because I think bProxy is just a variable name, it shouldn't affect the behavior of transaction.
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because grails naming agreement. See [Dependency Injection Basics](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/services.html) section to understand behaviour in your question.

Comment: OK, I read it, I think I should read the official doc more.
thanks for this information.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the proxy, you are not instantiating it as a spring service. At that point its just a normal class. To use it as a spring service it has to be injected as an service which you achieve by following the convention. Hope that helps